# Heroku Application Error while user login

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, visual-studio-code

Heroku Application Error appears when the user signed in with an email and password and the error removed when I set command $heroku restart

**The error**

`code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST 
path="/doctor/login"`

Comment: Check the logs for the reason for the error.

Comment: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/doctor/login"

Comment: Can you please place the error into your question for others to review. It will help answer your question.